# Focusrite USB Mic Drivers

Tags: windows-iot, c#

I wanted to use a Focusrite Solo to be able to use a better quality mic with my raspberry pi 3 with windows 10 IoT Core and a Voice recognition program I am developing.

I see it as a device in the web portal but my voice control program does not work. My suspicion is I need drivers or something to be able to use a device that needs drivers.

Is there a way I can add the drivers to Windows 10 IOT? 
If I plug in my cheapy USB mic it works but the quality of the mic is terrible and I get a lot of false recognition from my voice recognition program.

Comment: After hours of trying with the focus Rite I returned it and purchased the Blue-Icicle-XLR-Converter-Preamp xlr to usb adaptor. This adaptor did work with no drivers needed. However I still wish I could find a way to add AEC reference to make the mic ignore some of the ambient noise in the room so the recognizer would hear my voice better.